# uiview as optional parameters in swift

Tags: swift

I have a function where I am passing the `UIStackview` as a parameter. I want that parameter to be optional.

```
func render(parentview: UIStackView = nil) {
  // 
}
```

how can I make this function optional and how to give a default value to it?

Comment: Just add a question mark right after the type.

Comment: use func render(parentview: UIStackView? = nil) { }

Comment: This is in the *first* page of [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) free manual by Apple. You should really read it.

Comment: yes , got it now. what a silly question it was

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare method like below:

```
func test(_ myNumber: Int? = 2) { 
}
```

In above function, I have provided a default value as 2.

I can call the function as

```
test()
```

**or**

```
test(5)
```